# How to create an INDEX refering to columns of two tables

Tags: sql

I have to create an index out of this case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tab1.name
FROM tab1, tab2
WHERE tab1.s = tab2.s AND tab2 = something
```

How do you create an INDEX that is dependent of another table? And if I have (`GROUP BY name`) in a generic case does it change anything in the INDEX?

Comment: I would create two indexes: the first one on tab1.s and the second on tab2 (s,something)

Comment: Why don't you create a view of the two tables and then create the index on the two columns from the two different tables?

Comment: First suggestion , use [ANSI/ISO](https://docs.actian.com/vector/4.2/index.html#page/SQLLang/ANSI_2fISO_Join_Syntax.htm) join syntax. Based on the query you need  a key `tab1.s` and a composite key `(tab2.s,tab2.something)`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Not sure what RDBMS you're using - but most likely, an **index** is defined on **one** table - and thus can also use "only" columns from that one table ......